# List variable values that are checked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have gotten pretty far with this in jsFiddle, though I can't figure out why it's not adding a bullet to the first value..

http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/128/

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="one" />Option 1
    <input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="two" />Option 2
    <input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="three" />Option 3
    <input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="four" />Option 4
</div>

<div class="content"></div>

<script>
    $("input").click(function(e) {

    var selected = $("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function(i, el) {
        return el.name;
    }).get();

    $('.content').empty();

    $(".content").append(selected.join("<li>"));

});
</script>
```

​

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as well. While a jsfiddle is nice, it should not *be* the body of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pointy said, `join` will not add `li` when you have a single element. Also, you don't need to use `join` at all, simply add the elements with a single loop:

```
$("input").click(function(e) {
    var $content = $('.content').empty();
    $("#checkboxes input:checked").each(function(i, el) {
       $("<li>" + el.name + "</li>").appendTo($content);
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89tHX/)**.

Comment: THis is much better! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The `.join()` function only puts the string **between** elements.  The result is therefore

```
 name1<li>name2<li>name3
```

when you need

```
 <li>name1<li>name2<li>name3
```

Also, dropping `<li>` elements into a `<div>` is pretty questionable.

You can still use `.join()`, but you should add another `<li>` to the beginning of the result string when (after the join) it's not empty.

Comment: oh! What's a better one to use?

Comment: just prefix a `<li>` if `.length > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input").click(function(e) {
    var selected = $("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function(i, el) {
        return "<li>"+el.name+"</li>"
    }).get();
    $(".content").html(selected.join(""));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/129/)